# Is there a way to check if a bean is defined in spring context?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create an object factory, which will first check if a bean has been specifically define in spring context. If such a bean is not found, It would check for other ways to create the instance.

I have implemented it using the following code

```
try {
        component = (PageComponent) appContext.getBean(w.getName());
    } catch (org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
            component = loadFromDB(w, page);
    }
```

It is working, however an exception object is created whenever the bean is not available in Spring Context.

Is there a way to avoid this? or in other words Is there a way to check if a bean is defined in spring context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(appContext.containsBeanDefinition(w.getName()))
    ; // Get the bean
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanFactory.html#containsBeanDefinition-java.lang.String-

Comment: is there a way to validate the same in XML ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ApplicationContextRunner`

Suppose I have a bean that conditional on some config-prop.

```
class IsExistBeanTest {

  private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
      .withUserConfiguration(SomeConfig.class)                          

  @Test
  void TestIfBeanIsThereWhenPropsExist() {
    contextRunner
        .withPropertyValues("some-left-service=false")
        .run(context -> assertAll(
            () -> assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(SomeBean.class),
            () -> assertThat(context).doesNotHaveBean(SomeOtherBean.class)));
            () -> assertThat(context).hasBean(SomeBean2.class)));
           //() -> more test case
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`beanFactory.containsBean(w.getName())` will return a `boolean` value depending on if there's already a bean registered by this name. Take a look at [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#containsBean-java.lang.String-).

Do something like this

```
if (!((BeanFactory) applicationContext).containsBean(w.getName())) {
     component = loadFromDB(w, page);
}
```